# Unable to Fetch WebContent using ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add()

Tags: excel, vba

If I use parameters as variable then i will get the output

> "Response":"False","Error":"Movie not found"

i.e.

```
fname = Range("B1").Value
fyear = Range("C1").Value

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
   "URL;http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=fname&y=fyear", _
   Destination:=Range("B1"))
```

If i use this:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Jaws: The Revenge&y=1987", _
    Destination:=Range("A1"))
```

Then it will retrieve the result. 
 I am confused with this, Please help me to find out the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _"URL;http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" & fname & "&y=" & fyear, _ Destination:=Range("B1"))
```

you'll probably need to parse the fname data to replace spaces and other characters that aren't valid in URLs.

Comment: I used Trim(fname) to remove white spaces. But which din work. May I know any other parsing methods?

Comment: Actual spaces would be replaced by %20